# jQuery dont load until refresh?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a personal website to expand my jQuery knowledge. I have written this page in PHP and it works fine with no console errors:
http://sallibert.com/apps/notes/notes.php

But, when I call it using an include in the index file, the animation gets stuck on load:
http://sallibert.com/index.php#!notes

The JS links are good, and there are no bad links.

I have tried these different solutions and none of them work:

- Place the JS links in the body
- Replace `$('document').ready(function(){` with  `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`
- jQuery.noConflict();

Does anyone have any ideas to fix this bug?
Thanks for the help!

**EDIT :**

I have updated the links above, you can check it now. I have no errors logs on firefox but now on chrome, i got two of them. I try to solve them:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
The first bug is linked to this, i think.

And

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
First, i load append the html using the html, then, when the page is loaded, apply some JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
$('#horloge .app_logo').append('<img class="aigfix" id="aigS" src="img/aigS.png"     alt="" style="transform: rotate(314784deg);"><img class="aig" id="aigM" src="img/aigM.png" alt="" style="transform: rotate(5246deg);"><img class="aighfix" id="aigH" src="img/aigH.png" alt="" style="transform: rotate(437deg);">');
....
});

window.onload = function() // wait before load
   {
      var d    = new Date();
      var time = d.getSeconds() + 60 * d.getMinutes() + 3600 * d.getHours();

      var aigS = document.getElementById('aigS');
      var aigM = document.getElementById('aigM');
      var aigH = document.getElementById('aigH');

      aigS.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
      aigS.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
      aigS.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
      aigS.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
      aigS.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
      aigM.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
      aigM.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
      aigM.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
      aigM.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
      aigM.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
      aigH.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
      aigH.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
      aigH.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
      aigH.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
      aigH.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';

      setInterval(function() {
         time++;
            aigS.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
            aigS.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
            aigS.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
            aigS.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
            aigS.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + (time * 6) + 'deg)';
            aigM.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
            aigM.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
            aigM.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
            aigM.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
            aigM.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 10) + 'deg)';
            aigH.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
            aigH.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
            aigH.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
            aigH.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
            aigH.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + Math.round(time / 120) + 'deg)';
      }, 1000);
   }
```

the php include code is:

```
<?php
    $appid = strtolower($_GET['appid']);
    if($appid && file_exists('apps/'.$appid.'/'.$appid.'.php')){
        header('Location: apps/'.$appid.'/'.$appid.'.html');
    }
?>
```

Update2:
I just have seen that the apps in the folder are undefined. I call them using an array: $apps[1] = Array( 'Maps', Array('CV',Array('Complet','Expériences','Compétences','Diplomes','Autres','Rech‌​erche')), 'Messages', ... ); 
I have solved the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined.
But it didnt solve the main problem, the bug load of the notes apps.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there are several errors in the console, in particular the one being thrown at the beginning of your unload (aigS appears to be null) right before you run your animation code seems interesting...

Comment: What link to include jQuery did you use? Where is the website hosted?

Comment: i've seen your website and there is tons of console error. please provide sample of your php output and correct the errors from console

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload` might be executed before `$(document).ready`. If you use one type of onload event you should stick with it and not mixing them. Also try to not expect the document.ready event to be triggered in a specific order, you should trigger your own event if you need some cascading events :

```
//declare a custom event
$(document).on('myevent', function(e){

});

// trigger a custom event
$(document).trigger('myevent');
```

You should move the code from `window.load` to the jquery ready function.

**Date**

Instead of your formula you might prefer the `new Date().getTime() / 1000`

**toLowerCase error**

Change in plugins.js (line 75) from this :

```
cache = rows.map(function(){
    return $(this).children('.search_str').html().toLowerCase();
});
```

to :

```
cache = rows.map(function(){
    var el = $(this).children('.search_str');
    return el?el.html().toLowerCase():"";
});
```

Comment: I have put the append in the window.onload instead.

Comment: @zorg ok. still have issues? you can add `if(aigH){...` in the style set

Comment: I will rewrite the css for the clock after. I still have the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined. I work on it.

Comment: @zorg you should try to check the element existence before converting to lower case that's all

Comment: I have try your solution, doesnt seem to work too. I use the class .search_str to add the apps name on search page and the notes search items list. I just have seen that the apps in the folder are undefined. I call them using an array: $apps[1] = Array(
    'Maps',
    Array('CV',Array('Complet','Expériences','Compétences','Diplomes','Autres','Recherche')),
    'Messages',
...
);